# Npm install doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, ember.js, npm

i have an issue with nodejs. I'm trying to install ember.js library through the command line. When i launch "npm install" command this log appear:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'install' ]
    2 info using npm@2.11.3
    3 info using node@v0.12.7
    4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\Antonio/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
    5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\Antonio\package.json
    6 error install Couldn't read dependencies
    7 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Antonio\package.json'
    7 verbose stack     at Error (native)
    8 verbose cwd C:\Users\Antonio
    9 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    10 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
    11 error node v0.12.7
    12 error npm  v2.11.3
    13 error path C:\Users\Antonio\package.json
    14 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
    15 error errno -4058
    16 error package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Antonio\package.json'
    16 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
    16 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
    17 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]`

I've visited [NPM Troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) but i can't found the solution (i tried the three options but nothing happen).
Just to say: there is yet a folder named "npm" in AppData/Roaming.

Comment: I am getting the same error on Window 10.  Windows 7 seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to install ember is:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
ember new my-app
```

`npm install` by itself only works if you have a package.json in the directory where you type it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've already tried it, same error. In C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm there is a file named package.json, i've read that the command "npm install" serves for resolving dependencies(?) before  installing ember.js

Comment: npm install only works if there is a package.json *in the directory where you type it*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue trying to install some node modules to a fresh installation of Sails. I found the solution in this link: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9676

Just removed `node_modules` from my root and then `npm install` again, then I was able to install other modules as well.